# Vaadin Flow: get current QueryParameters during onAttach

Tags: request, vaadin, query-string, vaadin-flow

how does one reliably retrieve `QueryParameters` during `onAttach`?

### Situation:

My component needs these parameters for configuration purposes and as `beforeEnter` (which conveniently has `.getLocation`) is not called during the initial load I need to get the same information during `onAttach`.

---

### NOTE:

For some reason `VaadinRequest.getCurrent()` returns `null`

Comment: Is it possible for you to use url parameters instead of QueryParameters, because they are much easier to process by implementing HasUrlParameter interface in your view.

Comment: Ill give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case this wont be possible.
Our 'architecture' does not provide a direct association between Layouts and there content.

Comment: Interestingly the BeforeEvent used by setParameter contains the location.
I read it in the Layout and associated it with the UI using ComponentUtils#setData.
During the onAttach of my component I read the value again.

Comment: Are there any reasons for not having the Location in the AttachEvent?
If not I would like to open a Issue over on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `AttachEvent` does not know the `Location` the `BeforeEvent` of `setParameter` does.

### Workaround (simplified):

```
@Route("workaround")
public class Workaround extends FlexLayout implements AttachNotifier, HasUrlParameter<String> {
    private Location currentLocation = null;

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @OptionalParameter String parameter) {
        // called before onAttach
        currentLocation = event.getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent);

        QueryParameters qm = currentLocation.getQueryParameters();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```